# GridView to PDF without ITextSharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, gridview, itext

Is there any way to import data in pdf from gridview without using the itextsharp ?????

I am keen to look a code that will export all data of gridview into pdf without any 3rd Party dll.

Comment: is this web application or winform application ??

Comment: This is Web Application Using language is VB.NET

Comment: *pdf without any 3rd Party dll* - this essentially means that you want to create a PDF library of your own. Do you feel ready for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it easily without a third party DLL. Why don't you want to use 3rd party dll ?

If you really want to do it without any Dlls, you can use a report (.rdlc) that includes your data and then export the report in PDF format.

Please check this link :

[Exporting to Word PDF using Microsoft Report RDLC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492739/Exporting-to-Word-PDF-using-Microsoft-Report-RDLC)

Comment: I am Using Oracle not SQL so using .rdl not possible.Please suggest something relate to oracle ->gridview->pdf

Comment: .rdlc Reports are not related to SQL Server. You can use whatever datasource by using the correct provider.